# Cant create a react app using npx create-react-app due to 6 vulnerabilities

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: This is shown even after removing the create-react-app globally and clearing the npx cache]

I wanted to create a react app but it doesn't work properly it shows that there are 6 vulnerabilities and when I enter npm start it won't work

Comment: what command did you run? [edit] the question to include more details like this

Comment: Nothing in your image shows that that the command didn't work, just that you should update some npm packages.

Comment: Please provide the command you ran

Answer (score 0):

You must update your create-react-app installation to the latest version.

Run the following command to update the create-react-app package globally:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

If you're using Yarn, use the following command instead:

```
yarn global remove create-react-app
```

his command will remove the globally installed create-react-app package from your system.

After uninstalling the previous version, you can now install the latest version of create-react-app by running the following command:

Once the installation is complete, you can verify that create-react-app has been updated by running the following command:

```
create-react-app --version
```